# List型の初期化中に 条件式を入れることは可能ですか

Tags: c#, .net

C#.NET で書いています。
以下のようなコードがある場合、途中で条件式（IF文）で判定したいのですが、記述可能ですか。
可能なら、どのような書き方があるでしょうか。

```
prvate List<UserInfo>[] usersList = new List<UserInfo>[8];
usersList = new List<UserInfo> {
    new UsersInfo{ No=1, FileName="book1.xlsx" sheet=3},
    new UsersInfo{ No=2, FileName="book1.xlsx" sheet=3},  
    new UsersInfo{ No=3, FileName="book1.xlsx" sheet=4},
    new UsersInfo{ No=4, FileName="book1.xlsx" sheet=1}, 
　　　★★★ この時、↑↑↑の FileNameの値を条件で変えたいです★★★
　　　↓↓↓ 次のように書けるようですが、この場合、条件が増えたとき可読性に欠けます。
new UsersInfo{ No=4, FileName=(cond==2 ? "book3.xlsx" : "book1.xlsx"), sheet=1)
　　　★★★ IF文などで書く方法はあるでしょうか。★★★
　　　★★★ 書ける場合、どのように書けばいいですか★★★

　　　：
　　　：
}
```

Answer (score 2):

できません。

挙げられた構文は[コレクション初期化子](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers)と言って単に`Add`メソッドを呼び出すだけのものですので、追加時に条件を含めたいのであれば、素直に`Add`メソッドを呼び出すようにしてください。

Answer (score 0):

好きに関数書けば・・・
求めてるのは違う？

```
Func<string> getFileName = () =>
{
    if (cond == 2)
    {
        return "book3.xlsx";
    }
    return "book1.xlsx";
};
usersList = new List<UserInfo> {
    new UserInfo() {No = 1, FileName = "book1.xlsx", sheet = 3},
    new UserInfo() {No = 1, FileName = "book1.xlsx", sheet = 3},
    new UserInfo() {No = 1, FileName = "book1.xlsx", sheet = 4},
    new UserInfo() {No = 1, FileName = getFileName(), sheet = 1}
};
```